Permissions Policy Violation: Microphone Not Allowed in Outlook Add-In
I am developing an Outlook add-in that includes a speech recognition feature. Recently, I encountered the following error in the browser console:

outlook-web-16.01.js:20 [Violation] Permissions policy violation: microphone is not allowed in this document.

I am using outlook solutions MessageRead.js file.Visual studio 2022.
enter image description here
Investigation So Far:
Enabling Microphone Access: I have ensured that the microphone access is enabled in the browser settings.
Checked Permissions Policies: Ensured that the appropriate permissions policies are set in the HTML meta tags and headers.
Browser Updates: Suspecting that a recent browser update might be causing this issue.
Outlook Updates: Considering whether a recent update to Outlook might have affected permissions.
Browser: checked on Microsoft Edge , Chrome and outlook desktop
Operating System: Windows 11
